# Cannot add Qt in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013

I would like to use Qt in Visual Studio 2013. I installed Qt Version 5.0.2. Then,  I added Qt to Visual Studio. I defined the path as Qt 5.0.2 Version msvc2012_64. After creating a project, I built the solution. It gives that error:

```
1>qtmaind.lib(qtmain_win.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1700' doesn't match value '1800' in debar.obj
1>c:\Users\sercan\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Debar\x64\Debug\\Debar.exe : fatal error LNK1319: 1 mismatches detected
```

Is it related to compiler version?

Comment: You have downloaded a Qt version which was compiled with VS 2012 (version `1700`). This can not be linked with your application which was compiled with VS 2013 (version `1800`). Download a Qt version which was compiled with VS 2013 (e.g. [Qt 5.5](http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.5/5.5.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_64-5.5.0.exe)).

Answer (score 1):

Use this command on your Qt project file:

qmake -tp vc myprofile.pro

This generates the Visual Studio solution file. Within this solution add any necessary paths for Qt in Project Properties|Debugging|Environment e.g. Path=C:\ASL0632\asl-qt-4.7.4.3\asl-qt-4.7.4.3\bin